# Sort JSON array by an Array within Array

Tags: objective-c

I need to sort my json by an array within the array (hopefully that makes sense). In the JSON below, i need to sort all items by Distance/Miles. So my code is as follows but i get a crash where noted.

```
NSArray *beforeSortArray = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"items"];

NSSortDescriptor *distanceSortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"distance.miles"
                                                                                 ascending:YES
                                                                                  selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
        _arrAllKeys = [beforeSortArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[distanceSortDescriptor]];//CRASHES HERE
```

And my JSON snippet:

```
{
"items": [
    {
        "ID": "794",
        "title": "Here is a title",
        "price": "450.00",
        "date_time": "2015-04-18 15:24:23",
        "description": "Here is description",
        "category_id": "8",
        "distance": {
            "miles": 6465.5731978902,
            "kilometers": 10405.331432585
        },
        "images": [
            "http://myimageurl.com"
        ],
        "latitude": "00.00000",
        "longitude": "-00.0000",
        "location": "Kansas City KS",
        "creationdate": "Posted: Apr 18, 2015",
        "sellerUserID": "393",
        "seller_email": "email@email.com",
        "is_deleted": "0"
    },
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Pretty cowardly to down vote without explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of someone who posted an answer the later removed it which was very helpful. I'm not sure why it would have been removed because it got me on the right track. If you see this, thank you. I managed to get it working with the following:

```
         _arrAllKeys2 = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"items"];

        NSSortDescriptor *distanceSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"distance.miles" ascending:YES];

        _arrAllKeys = [_arrAllKeys2 sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[distanceSortDescriptor]];
```